# What is the best way to specify data with brackets in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

I've a page where field names are of type array.

```
eg. mapping[map][email_address][type]
```

Now in Vue, I want to set the default value and I'm doing it as below

```
new Vue({
    el: '#configure',
    data: {
        mapping: {
            map: {
                email_address: {
                    type: 'incoming_field'
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

But I get an error in console

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "map" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 

vue.js:569 [Vue warn]: Property or method "email_address" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 

vue.js:569 [Vue warn]: Error in render function: 
(found in <Root>)
```

What is the best way to handle such field names in Vuejs?

Answer (score 0):

As par you code, you have to do:

```
mapping['map']['email_address']['type']
```

or

```
mapping.map.email_address.type
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rethink your data to not have so many nested objects.

If you are setting a property directly within an object, it is good practice to use Vue.set to ensure [you do not break reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#How-Changes-Are-Tracked). Doing this will save you hours of headaches trying to figure out where something broke.

```
Vue.set(mapping.map.email_address, 'type', value_to_set)
```